# Restrict a login request to ROLE_ADMIN with Symfony API REST

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, symfony-security

I would like to enable admins to log in as any user he wants thanks to the user's matricule number. In config/packages/security.yaml I added this to my firewall:

```
admin_matricule:
      pattern: ^/api/admin/login_matricule
      stateless: true
      anonymous: false
      provider: app_user_provider
      json_login:
        check_path: /api/admin/login_matricule
        # success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        # failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - App\Security\AppAdminMatriculeAuthenticator
```

and this to access_control :

```
 access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/admin/login_matricule, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/api/docs, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

However, the access control seems to not be working because I can connect with users that haven't `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Comment: is it really true that you have the same entry three times in your security.yml?

Comment: Not at all lol, I made a mistake in my copy/paste. I'll rectify that, thanks

Comment: [Impersonation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're helping me a lot. It seems to be a very good solution